# FUNÇÃO(MÉTODO) EM PYTHON

Tags: python, python-3.x, funções

Bom estou tentando criar um programa de cadastro no python, mas um simples somente para testar o que tenho aprendido, mas tenho um problema, criei uma função e eu retorno e em seguida armazeno em uma variável porem ele executa a função sem eu querer, alguém para me ajudar? 
o problema ocorre na linha 49

```
# Codigo do usuario
c = 0

def menu():
    print("----------------------------------------")
    print("----------Sistema de Cadastro-----------")
    print("----------------------------------------")
    print("(1) buscar")
    print("(2) Cadastrar")
    print("(3) Excluir Cadastrado")
    print("(4) Sair")
    print("----------------------------------------")
    opcao = int(input("Digite o número: "))
    return opcao

def cadastro(c):
    # Coletando dados
    Nome = input("Digite o nome completo: ")
    Data_nasc = input("Digite a data de Nascimento: ")
    Natu = input("Digite a naturalidade: ")
    RG = input("Digite o RG: ")
    CPF = input("Digite o CPF: ")
    Cod = print("Codigo gerado:", c)
    print(50*'-')
    print("Cadastrado com Sucesso.")
    print(50*'-')

    # Configurando o Amarzenamento
    nome = []
    dataNasc = []
    natu = []
    rg = []
    cpf = []
    cod = []
    # codigo >>
    c += 1
    # Armazenando os dados
    nome.append(cadastro(Nome))
    dataNasc.append(Data_nasc)
    natu.append(Natu)
    rg.append(RG)
    cpf.append(CPF)
    cod.append(Cod)

    # Retornando Dados
    return nome, dataNasc, natu, rg, cpf, cod

# Armazenando dados na variavel
nome, dataNasc, natu, rg,cpf, cod = cadastro(c)

def busca():
    # Aprensentando com Sucesso
    print(50*'-')
    print('Cadastro encontrado.')
    print(50*'-')
    print("Nome:",nome[0])
    print("Data de Nascimento:", dataNasc[0])
    print("Naturalidade:", natu[0])
    print("RG:", rg[0])
    print("CPF:", cpf[0])
    print(50*'-')

opcao = menu()
if opcao == 4:
    pass
elif opcao == 2:
    cadastro(c)
elif opcao == 1:
    busca()
```

Obrigado por sua atenção.

Comment: Qual função ele executa sem você querer?

Comment: A função Cadastro

Answer (score 1):

O Erro tá aqui:

```
nome.append(cadastro(Nome))
```

Você chama cadastro de novo, remove `cadastro`

```
nome.append(Nome)
```

Comment: O erro ainda persiste, eu creio que seja na linha 49 (nome, dataNasc, natu, rg,cpf, cod = cadastro(c)) quando removo esta linha ele funciona normal.

Comment: @THW3SLEY Aqui funcionou normal

Comment: O problema consiste quando eu vou passar o valor da função, ele chama ela de novo, e eu não quero isso.

Answer (score -1):

Deveria funcionar assim:

```
# Codigo do usuario
c = 0

def menu():
    print("----------------------------------------")
    print("----------Sistema de Cadastro-----------")
    print("----------------------------------------")
    print("(1) buscar")
    print("(2) Cadastrar")
    print("(3) Excluir Cadastrado")
    print("(4) Sair")
    print("----------------------------------------")
    opcao = int(input("Digite o número: "))
    return opcao

def cadastro(c):
    # Coletando dados
    Nome = input("Digite o nome completo: ")
    Data_nasc = input("Digite a data de Nascimento: ")
    Natu = input("Digite a naturalidade: ")
    RG = input("Digite o RG: ")
    CPF = input("Digite o CPF: ")
    Cod = print("Codigo gerado:", c)
    print(50*'-')
    print("Cadastrado com Sucesso.")
    print(50*'-')

# Configurando o Amarzenamento
nome = []
dataNasc = []
natu = []
rg = []
cpf = []
cod = []
# codigo >>
c += 1
# Armazenando os dados
nome.append(Nome)
dataNasc.append(Data_nasc)
natu.append(Natu)
rg.append(RG)
cpf.append(CPF)
cod.append(Cod)

# Retornando Dados
return nome, dataNasc, natu, rg, cpf, cod

# Armazenando dados na variavel
nome, dataNasc, natu, rg,cpf, cod = cadastro(c)

def busca():
    # Aprensentando com Sucesso
    print(50*'-')
    print('Cadastro encontrado.')
    print(50*'-')
    print("Nome:",nome[0])
    print("Data de Nascimento:", dataNasc[0])
    print("Naturalidade:", natu[0])
    print("RG:", rg[0])
    print("CPF:", cpf[0])
    print(50*'-')

opcao = menu()
if opcao == 4:
    pass
elif opcao == 2:
    cadastro(c)
elif opcao == 1:
    busca()
```

Answer (score -2):

```
# Código do usuário
c = 0
def menu ():
 print("----------------------------------------")
 print("----------Sistema de Cadastro-----------")
 print("----------------------------------------")
 print("(1) buscar")
 print("(2) Cadastrar")
 print("(3) Excluir Cadastrado")
 print("(4) Sair")
 print("----------------------------------------")
 opcao = int(input("Digite o número: "))
 return opção

 opcao = menu()
```

Comment: O que é para ser esse código?